# pm2 is loading the older version of node js code even after pm2 kill command is executed

Tags: ubuntu, pm2

I have updated my source code in the server and I'm trying to run the latest code.

I'm using AWS Lightsail

The server is running on `Ubuntu 16.04`

Here is what I have tried

```
Step1:
pm2 kill 

Step 2:
NODE_ENV=production pm2 start server.js
```

But the older version of the code is running. How do I clear caches?

I have seen other answers and tried `reload` as well. Even that didn't work.

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I figured out that the problem was with Angular files replacement.

Deleting the `dist` folder and pasting the new `dist` folder from the development code was creating problems.

So, I had to just paste and replace the files which had changes.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more on this.  I have tried pm2 kill, but still have old code running. I deleted my entire project structure, and then pasted the new one, but, like I say, the old code is still running...

Comment: Don't delete the `dist` folder, just replace the files inside `dist` folder after `ng build`

Comment: I more meant how did you get past the issue once you had already deleted.  For me, I had to rename my startfile.